# opengl es nacl probleme

Tags: c++, opengl-es, google-nativeclient

I have an opengl es 2 code  working outside of NaCl but returns this error in Chrome:
[.PPAPIContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 3 
There is my code :

```
  static float theta = 0.0;
  glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1);
  glClearDepthf(1.0f);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);      
  g_matrices.PushMatrix();
  g_matrices.Rotatef( theta, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
  EnableGUIShader(SM_DEFAULT);
  GLfloat col[4] = {1.0f, 0.33f, 0.0f, 0.11f};
  GLfloat ver[3][3];
  ver[0][0] =  0.0f;
 ver[0][1] =  1.0f;
 ver[0][2] =  0.0f;
 ver[1][0] =  0.87f;
 ver[1][1] = -0.5f;
 ver[1][2] =  0.0f;
 ver[2][0] = -0.87f;
 ver[2][1] = -0.5f;
 ver[2][2] =  0.0f;  
 GLint   posLoc = GUIShaderGetPos();
 GLint   colLoc = GUIShaderGetCol();     
 glVertexAttribPointer(posLoc,  3, GL_FLOAT, 0, sizeof(ver), ver); 
 glVertexAttribPointer(1,  4, GL_FLOAT, 0, sizeof(col), col);
 glEnableVertexAttribArray(posLoc);
 glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
 glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
 glDisableVertexAttribArray(posLoc);
 glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
 DisableGUIShader();
 g_matrices.PopMatrix();
 theta += 1.0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the calls to `glVertexAttribPointer()` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` for the color, you ned to use `colLoc` for the first argument instead of `1`:

```
GLint   posLoc = GUIShaderGetPos();
GLint   colLoc = GUIShaderGetCol();     
glVertexAttribPointer(posLoc,  3, GL_FLOAT, 0, sizeof(ver), ver); 
glVertexAttribPointer(colLoc,  4, GL_FLOAT, 0, sizeof(col), col);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(posLoc);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(colLoc);
```

Also, if you want to pass in the colors as an array, you need a color per vertex. So for your 3 vertices, the color array would have to be `col[3][4]`. If you want to use the same color for all vertices, replace the `glVertexAttribPointer(colLoc, ...)` call with:

```
glVertexAttrib4f(colLoc, col[0], col[1], col[2], col[3]);
```

Comment: Glad to hear. The way this site works, you can upvote all answers that you found helpful, and accept the one that resolved your question. This way, it's clear that the question was answered. People often do searches for unanswered question to see where help is needed, and having answered questions clearly marked makes that much more efficient.